# Writing methods - Java salary program

Tags: java

I need to write a method for "r" regular workers and "o" overtime workers salary.

Regular is just hourly rate * hours worked.

Overtime is hourly rate * hours worked for the first 40 hours and every hour after 40 is (1.5)hourly rate.

***pre:***

`otStatus` must be either "o" for overtime or "r" for regular (the letter can be either upper or lower case).

***post:***

method returns the weekly salary of ot or regular

***Code:***

This is the code that I have right now:

```
public static double weeklySalary(double hourlyRate1, double hours1, String otStatus) { 

    double regularSalary;
    double otSalary;

    if (otStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("o")) {
        if (hours1 > 40 ) {
            salary = // What do I have to write here?
        }

        return salary;
    }

    if (otStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) {

        salary = hours1 * hourlyRate1;

    }

    return salary;



    return 0; //incase nothing is true so program doesn't crash
}
}
```

also, if i need to print this out:

System.out.printf("For a(n) overtime worker earning" + hourlyRate + "per hour who works" + hours + "hours, $%.2f is the weekly salary", salary);

How do I make salary change each time depending on overtime status?

Comment: Your second `return` statement is useless and will cause an compile error because it could never be accessed

Comment: You need to learn the basics of the language. From your code it seems you have no understanding of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First 40 hours, standard hourly rate, extra hours, 1.5 * hourly rate, like you say:

```
if (hours1 > 40 ) {
    salary = 40 * hourlyRate1 + (hours1 - 40) * 1.5 * hourlyRate1;
} else {
    salary = hours1 * hourlyRate1;
}
```

Comment: also, if i need to print this out:

System.out.printf("For a(n) overtime worker earning" + hourlyRate + "per hour who works" + hours + "hours, $%.2f is the weekly salary", salary);

How do I make salary change each time depending on overtime status?

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution:

```
public static double getSalary(double rate, double hours, String status) {
    if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("o") && hours > 40) 
        return 40 * rate + (1.5 * rate) * (hours-40);
    return rate * hours;
}
```

Comment: Why do you call this quick? There are 4 lines that you can match to one

Comment: Took like 30 seconds to write, and besides the guy just wants his homework done, he doesn't seem to care about understanding, so does it really matter?

Comment: For the OP it doesn't matter (and thats why I downvoted the OP's post), but for future readers it matters

Comment: What a horrible assumption and judgement. This is not for a class at all. I'm trying to learn coding during my free time. Of course I care about understanding. Is there anything in my post that indicated such a thing?? @chrisgray

Comment: @kenwoodjen Your post is very low quality, and it seems like you just posted an excercise (likely homework) in your question. And please don't accept the other answer because you don't like the one that posted the answer - this is a great answer for the horrible question